# Jasper report error : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "jasperTemplate"

Tags: jasper-reports

I am build an report using jasper-6.2.2 version. I use jasper studio 6.2.2 version. While in the development mode its running fine. When I deployed on tomcat it gives this below error.

I use jdk-1.6 version.

I could not understand where is the problem. How to resolve this issue.

```
ERROR [http-8080-5] (Digester.java:1770) - Parse Error at line 3 column 280: Document root element "jasperTemplate", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "jasperTemplate", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1621)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1900)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1359)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1316)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3095)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:921)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1916)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlTemplateLoader.loadTemplate(JRXmlTemplateLoader.java:199)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlTemplateLoader.load(JRXmlTemplateLoader.java:248)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlTemplateLoader.loadTemplate(JRXmlTemplateLoader.java:173)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillReportTemplate.loadTemplate(JRFillReportTemplate.java:119)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillReportTemplate.evaluate(JRFillReportTemplate.java:89)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.collectTemplates(JRBaseFiller.java:740)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.collectTemplateStyles(JRBaseFiller.java:763)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.collectStyles(JRBaseFiller.java:711)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.loadStyles(JRBaseFiller.java:658)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:550)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:414)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:121)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:667)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:983)
    at com.gold.eloop.server.reports.overview.OverviewReport.createJasperFile(OverviewReport.java:329)
    at com.gold.eloop.server.remoteservices.OverviewReportServiceRemote.saveImageAndJasper(OverviewReportServiceRemote.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Error parsing template XML.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlTemplateLoader.loadTemplate(JRXmlTemplateLoader.java:211)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlTemplateLoader.load(JRXmlTemplateLoader.java:248)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlTemplateLoader.loadTemplate(JRXmlTemplateLoader.java:173)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillReportTemplate.loadTemplate(JRFillReportTemplate.java:119)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillReportTemplate.evaluate(JRFillReportTemplate.java:89)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.collectTemplates(JRBaseFiller.java:740)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.collectTemplateStyles(JRBaseFiller.java:763)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.collectStyles(JRBaseFiller.java:711)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.loadStyles(JRBaseFiller.java:658)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:550)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:414)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:121)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:667)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:983)
    at com.gold.eloop.server.reports.overview.OverviewReport.createJasperFile(OverviewReport.java:329)
    at com.gold.eloop.server.remoteservices.OverviewReportServiceRemote.saveImageAndJasper(OverviewReportServiceRemote.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "jasperTemplate", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1621)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1900)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1359)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1316)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3095)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:921)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1916)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlTemplateLoader.loadTemplate(JRXmlTemplateLoader.java:199)
    ... 37 more
```

Somewhere, I read that 6.3.1 version contains extra attribute than 6.2.2 version. At initially I use 6.3.1 but later on I changed it to 6.2.2 but whenever I try to remove "uuid" attributes from the jrxml components, it automatically back when file saved.

What is the issue exactly, what should I do ? Please anyone help me from this jasper reporting!!!!!
:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is caused by a JasperReports style template (*.jrtx file) that you use in your report.

Prior to 6.3.0, style templates used a DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE jasperTemplate
  PUBLIC "-//JasperReports//DTD Template//EN"
  "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jaspertemplate.dtd">
```

Starting with 6.3.0, the templates use an XML schema (but the DTD is still supported for backward compatibility):

```
<jasperTemplate xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/template" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/template http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jaspertemplate.xsd">
```

The problem in your case seems to be that you are using a 6.3.0 style template in JasperReports 6.2.2.  Which will not work, make sure that your *.jrtx file has a DOCTYPE and no xmlns and xsi:schemaLocation attributes.